# IFrame should breakout, when a link in the IFrame was clicked

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Webapp, which just put a layer over a website (http://mywebapp.com/http://www.example-website.com/).
The Website is embedded in an IFrame, so I don't know when the URL of the Website changed. I'd like the have this behaviour: "When a link was clicked in the IFrame, the IFrame should breakout of my window".

I also created for Chrome and Firefox an extension, that is just an icon, which puts "http://mywebapp.com/" for the current URL in the current selected tab.

Is it possible to achieve this behaviour with an extension?

Comment: What does "breakout" mean in this context?

Comment: That the IFrame is now the only shown website.

Comment: if (top.location!= self.location) {
       top.location = self.location.href;
    }

Comment: That would be the code in the IFrame.

Comment: what do you mean by breakout,does it mean that iframe should not be displayed after the click.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found something called content scripts.

[Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts)

[Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)

I hope i can access with these extensions the IFrame, I'll give it a try.